# Elimination of intensifiers and downtoners

Tags: sentence-meaning

Is there any paper/work to prove that elimination of intensifiers and down toner from a sentence keep the meaning  of sentence same?

Comment: It would be nice to have an example of what you mean.

Comment: @VictorBazarov This seems to refer to: http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/downtonerterm.htm and http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/intensifierterm.htm - In which case I'm not sure the thing we're proving is necessarily true. I can imagine some sentences I could construct where the meaning would be modified if *both* were used together vs. none at all.

Comment: Example: "The first experiment went somewhat according to plan, but the second was a total success." vs. "The first experiment went according to plan, but the second was a success." The meaning might still be there, but it's very easy to conclude the sentence is just filler in the second case.